# How should I clean this data by eliminating the rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset about various infrastructural parameters of various countries.
`country_df.info()`

```
RangeIndex: 229 entries, 0 to 228
Data columns (total 50 columns):
 #   Column                                                      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                                                      --------------  -----  
 0   country                                                     229 non-null    object 
 1   Region                                                      229 non-null    object 
 2   Surface area (km2)                                          229 non-null    object 
 3   Population in thousands (2017)                              229 non-null    int64  
 4   Population density (per km2, 2017)                          229 non-null    float64
 5   Sex ratio (m per 100 f, 2017)                               229 non-null    float64
 6   GDP: Gross domestic product (million current US$)           229 non-null    int64  
 7   GDP growth rate (annual %, const. 2005 prices)              229 non-null    object 
 8   GDP per capita (current US$)                                229 non-null    float64
 9   Economy: Agriculture (% of GVA)                             229 non-null    object 
 10  Economy: Industry (% of GVA)                                229 non-null    float64
 11  Economy: Services and other activity (% of GVA)             229 non-null    float64
 12  Employment: Agriculture (% of employed)                     229 non-null    object 
 13  Employment: Industry (% of employed)                        229 non-null    object 
 14  Employment: Services (% of employed)                        229 non-null    object 
 15  Unemployment (% of labour force)                            229 non-null    object 
 16  Labour force participation (female/male pop. %)             229 non-null    object 
 17  Agricultural production index (2004-2006=100)               229 non-null    int64  
 18  Food production index (2004-2006=100)                       229 non-null    int64  
 19  International trade: Exports (million US$)                  229 non-null    object 
 20  International trade: Imports (million US$)                  229 non-null    object 
 21  International trade: Balance (million US$)                  229 non-null    object 
 22  Balance of payments, current account (million US$)          229 non-null    object 
 23  Population growth rate (average annual %)                   229 non-null    object 
 24  Urban population (% of total population)                    229 non-null    float64
 25  Urban population growth rate (average annual %)             229 non-null    object 
 26  Fertility rate, total (live births per woman)               229 non-null    object 
 27  Life expectancy at birth (females/males, years)             229 non-null    object 
 28  Population age distribution (0-14 / 60+ years, %)           229 non-null    object 
 29  International migrant stock (000/% of total pop.)           229 non-null    object 
 30  Refugees and others of concern to UNHCR (in thousands)      229 non-null    object 
 31  Infant mortality rate (per 1000 live births                 229 non-null    object 
 32  Health: Total expenditure (% of GDP)                        229 non-null    float64
 33  Health: Physicians (per 1000 pop.)                          229 non-null    object 
 34  Education: Government expenditure (% of GDP)                229 non-null    object 
 35  Education: Primary gross enrol. ratio (f/m per 100 pop.)    229 non-null    object 
 36  Education: Secondary gross enrol. ratio (f/m per 100 pop.)  229 non-null    object 
 37  Education: Tertiary gross enrol. ratio (f/m per 100 pop.)   229 non-null    object 
 38  Seats held by women in national parliaments %               229 non-null    float64
 39  Mobile-cellular subscriptions (per 100 inhabitants)         229 non-null    object 
 40  Mobile-cellular subscriptions (per 100 inhabitants).1       229 non-null    object 
 41  Individuals using the Internet (per 100 inhabitants)        229 non-null    int64  
 42  Threatened species (number)                                 229 non-null    object 
 43  Forested area (% of land area)                              229 non-null    object 
 44  CO2 emission estimates (million tons/tons per capita)       229 non-null    int64  
 45  Energy production, primary (Petajoules)                     229 non-null    int64  
 46  Energy supply per capita (Gigajoules)                       229 non-null    object 
 47  Pop. using improved drinking water (urban/rural, %)         229 non-null    object 
 48  Pop. using improved sanitation facilities (urban/rural, %)  229 non-null    object 
 49  Net Official Development Assist. received (% of GNI)        229 non-null    int64  
dtypes: float64(8), int64(8), object(34)
memory usage: 89.6+ KB
```

I saw that many columns were of the datatype `object`, but they should've been `float`. So I tried converting one of those columns using

`pd.to_numeric(country_df["Employment: Services (% of employed)"], errors= "ignore")`

and the output was

```
1      40.3
2      54.7
3       ...
4       -99
       ... 
224     -99
225    34.7
226    49.2
227    35.3
228    25.2
Name: Employment: Services (% of employed), Length: 229, dtype: object
```

As you can see, it fails to convert the type. On further looking , I found that the column looked something like this

```
0                                   28.5
1                                   40.3
2                                   54.7
3                                    ...
4                                    -99
5                                   58.2
6                                    ...
7                                    ...
8                                   73.1
9                                   49.3
10                                  85.1
11                                  76.1
12                                  69.7
13                                  49.1
14                                  81.9
15                                  65.6
16                                  40.3
17                                  77.9
18                                  58.4
19                                  77.6
20                                  67.9
21                                  46.6
22                                  87.6
23                                  33.7
24                                  49.4
25                                   -99
26                                  51.7
27                                  59.4
28                                  63.2
29                                   ...
30                                  80.1
31                                  64.1
32                                  15.1
33                                   6.3
34                                  61.3
35                                  38.0
36                                  29.5
37                                  78.4
38                                  83.6
39                                  23.4
40                                  21.4
41                                  70.5
42                                  67.5
43                                  84.9
44                                  82.1
45                                  49.1
46                                  69.9
47                                  32.8
48                                  33.5
49                                  84.0
50                                  69.3
51                                  64.0
52                                  75.3
53                                  79.2
54                                  60.5
55                                  21.8
56                                  28.9
57                                  78.4
58                                  53.2
59                                   ...
60                                  70.0
61                                  55.1
62                                  49.3
63                                  61.2
64                                  63.2
65                                  35.4
66                                  67.3
67                                  21.1
68                                   -99
69                                   ...
70                                  75.8
71                                  73.8
72                                  76.8
73                                  58.3
74                                  74.2
75                                  64.8
76                                  55.2
77                                  44.1
78                                  71.2
79                                  43.8
80                                   -99
81                                  72.1
82                                  82.5
83                                   -99
84                                  65.5
85                                  85.7
86                                  49.4
87                                  34.1
88                                  22.9
89                                  56.2
90                                  40.6
91                                   -99
92                                  49.0
93                                  65.9
94                                  78.2
95                                  31.2
96                                  46.2
97                                  50.9
98                                  58.6
99                                  77.4
100                                  ...
101                                 81.0
102                                 69.4
103                                 66.8
104                                 69.8
105                                 80.2
106                                 61.6
107                                 29.5
108                                  ...
109                                 70.1
110                                 49.8
111                                 17.7
112                                 69.7
113                                 69.4
114                                 40.3
115                                 43.0
116                                 55.8
117                                  -99
118                                 66.8
119                                 88.5
120                                 16.5
121                                 25.4
122                                 60.9
123                                 69.5
124                                 28.6
125                                 77.9
126                                  ...
127                                 69.0
128                                 50.2
129                                 67.5
130                                  -99
131                                 61.3
132                                  -99
133                                  -99
134                                 51.0
135                                 75.2
136                                  -99
137                                 46.8
138                                 21.0
139                                 61.7
140                                 56.3
141                                  -99
142                                 16.5
143                                 81.9
144                                 70.1
145                                 72.6
146                                 61.4
147                                 23.3
148                                 57.4
149                                  ...
150                                  ...
151                                 77.6
152                                 55.4
153                                 38.1
154                                  ...
155                                 65.9
156                                 26.0
157                                 61.0
158                                 58.3
159                                 56.1
160                                 59.5
161                                 68.2
162                                 80.5
163                                 44.7
164                                 70.3
165                                 40.3
166                                 46.8
167                                 66.1
168                                 17.8
169                                  ...
170                                  ...
171                                 67.6
172                                  -99
173                                 61.8
174                                 79.8
175                                  ...
176                                 64.3
177                                 71.4
178                                 27.9
179                                 56.1
180                                 78.2
181                                 25.5
182                                 82.6
183                                  -99
184                                 62.2
185                                 61.5
186                                 49.5
187                                 23.2
188                                 67.7
189                                  -99
190                                 76.8
191                                 46.6
192                                 61.5
193                                 46.7
194                                 74.3
195                                 61.0
196                                 79.9
197                                 76.1
198                                 42.3
199                                 29.4
200                                 43.3
201                                 54.5
202                                 47.2
203                                 28.7
204                                  -99
205                                 38.5
206                                 64.3
207                                 58.9
208                                 52.9
209                                 44.7
210                                  ...
211                                  -99
212                                 20.5
213                                 59.7
214                                 75.4
215                                 80.4
216                                 26.7
217                                 81.3
218                                 65.2
219                                 70.8
220                                 47.1
221                                 31.8
222                                 61.3
223                                 35.2
224                                  -99
225                                 34.7
226                                 49.2
227                                 35.3
228                                 25.2
```

These have the datatype `str` and hence can't be converted.
How should I deal with them? I want to eliminate those rows entirely, because I think they'll have random values in the different columns as well. But how do I delete the rows based on that criteria?
I want to check the entire dataframe, all columns and rows.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what were your results? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with sample input, code, and expected output, so that we know how to offer specific help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to solve it.
I used this code to create a list of rows that I want to drop

`bad_country = list(country_df[country_df["Employment: Services (% of employed)"] == "..."].index)`
`country_df.drop(country_df.index[bad_country], axis=0, inplace=True)`